# Query ElasticSearch From Node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a Node.js application. I need to query an ElasticSearch instance that's running on `http://myserver.com` to see if it still "alive". I'm trying to identify two things:

1. What is the most performant way to query ElasticSearch from Node.js? I know I can run queries against ElasticSearch in PostMan. For that reason, I think I can just use the `http` module in node. Yet, I'm not sure if this is really the most performant approach.
2. What is the smallest query I can run against ElasticSearch just to see if its running? I know if I was hitting a SQL database, I could just use `SELECT 1`. Is there something similar in ElasticSearch?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nodejs, you can use. Elasticsearch client [elasticsearchjs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/)

And, You can [ping the cluster](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html#_ping_the_cluster) to see if it is running.

ie.

```
client.ping({
  requestTimeout: 1000,
  // undocumented params are appended to the query string
  hello: "elasticsearch!"
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
  }
});
```

I think that helps, Good luck in starting elasticsearch in nodejs.

Comment: HI Can you please explain connecing  to a cluster instead of a single node in same situation?